# How to prove: If $(\omega, <) \equiv \mathcal{M}$, then $(\omega, <) \prec_{f} \mathcal{M}$

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

To prove that

> If $(\omega, <) \equiv \mathcal{M}$, then there exists a function $f: \omega \to M$ (the domain of $\mathcal{M}$) such that $(\omega, <) \prec_{f} \mathcal{M}$.

where,

the symbol $\equiv$ denotes ["elementary equivalence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence), and $\prec_{f}$ ["elementary embedding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence#Elementary_embeddings) with the function $f$.

---

***My thought: (may be totally wrong)*** I think any function $f$ which is order preserving suffices. However, how to construct such a function or to justify its existence? Furthermore, how to formally prove that $(\omega, <) \prec_{f} \mathcal{M}$ (what about induction on formulas)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of the theory of $(\omega,<)$ then $\mathcal{M}$ must possess an initial $\omega$ sequence. Because all of these elements are definable in $\mathcal{M}$: The first element, the second etc all first order.
Now its easy to check, using the definability of all the elements, that this initial segment is an elementary substructure.

Comment: Thanks. I got the basic idea. However, what does "all first order" mean? How to check that the initial segment is an elementary substructure "using the definability of all the elements"? Is it OK to define a function $f: \omega \to M$ recursively?